# $\sqrt{7}$ ,$\sqrt {7 - \sqrt {7}}$,$\sqrt {7 - \sqrt {7 + \sqrt {7}}}$,$\sqrt{7-\sqrt {7 + \sqrt {7 - \sqrt {7}}}}$, ...

Tags: calculus, limits

$\sqrt{7}$ ,$\sqrt {7 - \sqrt {7}}$,$\sqrt {7 - \sqrt {7 + \sqrt {7}}}$,$\sqrt{7-\sqrt {7 + \sqrt {7 - \sqrt {7}}}}$, ...

Find the limit of this sequence

It's easy to show that the limit is $2$ if it exsits, but why does it exist?

$a_{n+2}=\sqrt{7-\sqrt {7 + a_{n}}}$

Thus if $a_{n}>2$ , then $a_{n+2}<2$ ,and $a_{n+4}>2$.

Comment: Can you write down more terms or general formula? (rule for $+$'s and $-$'s).

Comment: You know $2$ is a fixed point of $\sqrt{7-\sqrt{7+x}}$. You must show that (starting from $\sqrt{7}=2.65..$) we have $\left|\sqrt{7-\sqrt{7+x}}-2\right|<\left|x-2\right|$. Btw., once you got your answer, I'd say you should then take the magic "$7$" out of the game and find out for which numbers this holds. I'd guess for any number bigger than $4$.

Comment: @NikolajK Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 3):

The limit exists since the map
$$\varphi : x \mapsto \sqrt{7-\sqrt{7+x}} $$
makes the distance from $2$ smaller and smaller (it is a contraction).

This follows from the fact that the Taylor series of $\varphi(x)$ around $x=2$ is given by:
$$\varphi(x) = 2-\frac{x-2}{24}+\frac{5(x-2)^2}{6912}-\ldots $$
hence:
$$\left|\varphi(x)-2\right|\approx\frac{|x-2|}{24}.$$